# add all ppas then update or one by one ppa-update?

Tags: ppa

quick question, I'm wondering if it's better to add all ppas first then do 1 update or should I add each ppa one by one and update each time?

Comment: "better" is subjective so whatever your preference is go for it. From a system's point of view it is the same. If you add them manually adding all might be quicker.

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm creating a script for installing my programs and configurations, that why I'm wondering if there is a difference